# Setting the foreign key relating to another table using for loop in python/sqlite3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm learning python and sql ad I have this exercise where I'm scraping a book website. I've done the scraping 'beginner level" and I've added the scraped data to a data base.

I have two tables (categories, books) and i use a foreign key in books table to relate with the category table

I'm using a for loop to achieve writing the data to the database that but I can't manage to set the foreign key for the books table to relate to categories table.

any help!!!

Here is my code:

```
url = "http://books.toscrape.com/index.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , "html.parser")
lists = soup.find_all('ul' , {"class":"nav nav-list"})
ordlist = lists[0].find_all('a')
    
for i in range(1,len(ordlist)):   #for loop to loop inside the whole list
    category_name = ordlist[i].get_text().strip()
    category_url = ordlist[i].get('href')
      
    connection = sqlite3.connect("Books Scraping DataBase.db")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName, CategoryUrl) VALUES (?,?)"
    data = [category_name, category_url]
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
    connection.commit()
    #connection.close()
    
   #print(categorey_list +'   ---   '+ category_url)
    new_url = url.replace("index.html", category_url)
   #print(new_url)
    response = requests.get(new_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , "html.parser")
    rows = soup.find_all('li',{'class':'col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3'})
    print(f'Adding {category_name} Books Category into the Books Scraping DataBase ')
    
    for j in range(len(rows)):  #for loop to fetch all books from all categories
        h1 = rows[j].find('h3').get_text().split(":")[0]
        price = float(rows[j].find('p' , {'class' : 'price_color'}).get_text().split('£')[1])
        rate = rows[j].find("p").attrs["class"][1] 
        sql = "INSERT INTO Books (Title, Price, Rating) VALUES (?,?,?)"
        data = [h1, price, rate]
        cursor.execute(sql, data)
        connection.commit()

connection.close()        
print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it, but please if there is a better solution I will appreciate it

I added this code before the second for loop

```
row_id = cursor.lastrowid
```

That way I can store the category id in row_id and use it in the second for loop at assign as foreign key for the books in that category